# how can I hide a terminal window or put it to tray?

Tags: macos, bash, mac, terminal

I have a command line program that I configured to launch at startup with a bash file, but it's kind of annoying to have to have it open all the time. Is there a way to hide it?

I'm on OSX 10.11.6

Here's my bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
node /Users/Dan/run.js
```

Comment: Can't you just minimize the window by clicking yellow button?

Comment: @john I don't want to minimize it, it's annoying to have it in the dock. I want it either in system tray or completely invisible.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at launchd and try to run the process as real background process using a LaunchDaemon or a LaunchAgent.

Have a look at http://www.launchd.info for more infos